# _.each context variable

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I don't understand the purpose of a context variable for many of the underscore.js functions. What purpose does it serve. I know that it binds "this" in the iterator callback, but I don't understand the practical application of it.

```
var context = {'a': 'a'};
_.each([1, 2, 3], function(element, index, list)
{
    console.log(this);
    console.log(element);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(list);
}, context);
```

Answer (score 2):

Underscore's `_.each` looks like this:

`_.each(list, iterator, [context])`

Contexts are very useful when your iterator is a member of some object you've created, and you want to execute that function in the scope of the object and not of the window. If your pre-written function that you're using as an iterator uses `this` to refer to an instance of an Object (as is generally the case), calling the function without context will result in `this` referring to the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful if your *iterator* function is something like a *method* on an object:

```
var context = {'a': 'a',  foo: function(x) { console.log( this.a + x); }};
_.each([1, 2, 3], context.foo, context);
```

Comment: This is the easiest to understand answer. It might also be noted that the context is unnecessary if you are passing in an anonymous function like the original poster does in their example.

Answer (score 0):

It's realy helpfull when you dont need a context change, don't forget about it's hard dependecy brother Backbone.

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
//..
    _toggleActive: function (model, state) {
        model.set({
            active: state
        });
    },
    deactivateAll: function () {
        // analog _.each(this.models , func, [context])
        this.each(function (model) {
            // call the method of collection from context
            this._toggleActive(model, false);
        }, this);
    }
//..
});
```

Or just for debug

```
_.each([1,2,3], function(item, i, arr){
    this.log(item, i);
}, console);
```

Comment: For the code showing debug, why would you need a context of console?

Comment: Yeah, you right, changed to necessary thing for context, but a low winning )

Answer (score 0):

As of version  there are about 21 functions in underscore that accept 'context' as last optional argument.

_.each(list, iteratee(element, index, list), [context])

Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function. The iteratee is bound to the context object, if one is passed.

```
var array_1 = ['asdf', 'ghjk', 'lzxc', 'vbnm', 'qwer', 'tyui', 'op'];
var array_2 = [1,0,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6];

_.each(array_1, function(element, index, list){
    console.log(this.length - index + " - " + this[this.length - index]);
}, array_2);
```

will output

```
1 - asdf
0 - ghjk
2 - lzxc
9 - vbnm
3 - qwer
8 - tyui
4 - op
```

here this is corresponds to the context array array_2.